# Jssor cursor when mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, jssor

I'm missing one customization for my webpage: the cursor for mouse hover on the images. It's been set to the "cursor: move" to indicate that the images can be dragged but I have a customized cursor and want to replace it. Any hints on where this configuration is?

EDIT: I'm aware that I can customize cursor using own image and I did it for other parts of the web. But Jssor customizes the mouse after it initializes and my image for cursor won't be loaded. Jssor has a list of configuration but I can't find where to set cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use CSS to add a class like this:

```
.cursor {
    cursor: url('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur'), default !important;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('yourimage').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass('cursor');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`cursor:  url(custom.png), auto;`

That's usually enough for me, you can pass more parameters in, check them out the [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property).  Cheers